# GitHub Actions Trigger Another Workflow is not run on the commit already, then fetch artifacts

Tags: git, github-actions, workflow, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

We have added a self-hosted device that we want to use for soaking tests. The idea is that we already have a worklow job that builds our engine (i.e. `build.yml`). Following this is the user wants they can manually trigger another soaking workflow job (i.e. `soaking.yml`) which downloads artifacts from `build.yml` and uses that within its tests.

I found a way to download the artifacts as shown below by adding the following in my `soaking.yml` workflow;

```
      - name: Download artifact
        id: download-artifact
        uses: dawidd6/action-download-artifact@v2
        with:
          commit: ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha || github.sha }}
          name: engine.*
          workflow: build.yml
          workflow_conclusion: success
          if_no_artifact_found: fail
          name_is_regexp: true
```

However I am unable to find a method to initially check the status of the `build.yml` workflow and start if it required. I basically need a pre-requisite task which;

Checks the status of `build.yml` workflow and if it ran with the same commit number (i.e. `github.sha` ) for the following cases;

- if one is running wait for it to complete
- if one has already ran, then continue
- else, start the workflow and wait for it to complete.

I found items like `workflow_run` which allow you to specify which task must run beforehand. However, I do not always want the soaking to run following a `build.yml` and I want it to be run manually via a `workflow_dispath` option.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: While what you are describing is most probably somehow possible, I'd argue it'll end in a quite complex setup.

Since you want to only trigger your second pipeline manually anyway, couldn't you just fail if the artifact doesn't exist?

Or, assuming the build pipeline runs on every commit that gets pushed, you could _wait on that pipeline_ instead of checking it's success.

https://github.com/marketplace/actions/wait-for-other-pipelines
or https://github.com/marketplace/actions/wait-on-check might work for you in that case.

Comment: The issue is I want the `soaking` test to be able to be triggered either manually or automatically (say at weekly intervals).